# File specified cannot be found.Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I can not run my program on Visula Studio 2022.What is the problem, what is the solution?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm3rn.png)

Comment: Look at the Visual Studio output pane. What does it say there?

Answer (score 1):

As said above, look at what Visual Studio is telling you.

The relevant part of the output pane is

> main already defined in ConsoleApplication1C++.obj

Every C++ program must have one `main` function, but (presumably) your VS project includes two mains, one in Source.cpp and one in ConsoleApplication1C++.cpp.

The solution is to only have one main per program. If you want two programs then create two separate projects.